# How do I configure LESS source mapping to work with Chrome for a ASP.Net MVC project that uses Web Essentials 2013 (2.5.3)?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, less, web-essentials

In Visual Studio 2013 under `Tools > Options > Web Essentials > Less` the following is set:

[image]

Looking at the `.less` file with the side by side view provided by Web Essentials 2013 in Visual Studio 2013, the compiled version has a source map link a the bottom:

[image]

However, when run the solution and load Chrome all I am seeing is the compiled version of the `.less` file:

[image]

Chrome Developer Tools settings are appear correct:

[image]

So don't think that is the issue. According to [Rob Dodson](http://robdodson.me/debug-less-with-chrome-developer-tools/), the expected result when clicking a line number after selecting an element is to see uncompiled `.less` like so:

[image]

Could this be a bundling issue? Have looked into that too with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem to yours and here's what I've discovered including a workaround:

1. Web Essentials 2013 (WE2013) generates a map file that has a filename format of $filename$.map.  So if say your file is named *global.less*, WE2013 will generate a *global.css.map* file.
2. Chrome Dev Tools looks for the comment at the end of your generated css file that references the map file.  For example: /*# sourceMappingURL=global.css.map */
3. Unfortunately, Chrome Dev Tools chokes on a map file that contains the same name as the generated css file (in this case global.css).  This works fine if you manually change the map file name from *global.css.map* to *global.less.map*.  You have to remember to modify the comment line in your generated global.css file to read  /*# sourceMappingURL=global.less.map */
4. This is obviously not an ideal workflow for troubleshooting your less files in chrome dev tools, but I'm hoping the WE2013 folks will put out a patch that either allows the map filename to be specified by the user, or auto-generate one that has a format of *filename.less.map*.  Until such a time though, if you're still invested in WE2013, then you can use the workaround above to get around the problem.

Comment: I still can't get my Styles tab to show the .scss styles. Only .css :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should enable BrowserLink feature in WebEssential extension. In my workspace this settings are located in standart bar between "**Start debug**" button and "**Configuration manager**"

[image]